# jQuery .next('td').text() not having desired effect

Tags: jquery

I have a table that I would like to get a value from. When the user clicks the icon in a cell I need the text from the cell directly to it's right. I am using this code to create the table.

**php**

```
$project_info = $db->prepare("
    SELECT  projects.id,
        projects.project_name,                  
        projects.pm,    
        // ...more columns   
    FROM projects
    WHERE account_id = ?                        
"); 

$project_info->bindValue(1, $aid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$project_info->execute();       

echo "<table class='projects_contentTable'>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
// ...more headers   

while ($row = $project_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/edit.png' class='edit_project_record'/>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/view.png' class='view_project_record'/>" . "</td>";              
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
    // ...more td's
    echo "</tr>";               
}
echo "</table>";
```

and this code to get the value from the cell

**jquery**

```
$('body').on('click', '.view_project_record', function() {
    pid = $(this).next('td').text();
    alert(pid);
    loadProject();
});
```

Now when the alert fires it sends me a blank box, as though the 'td' holds no value.

This is what else I've tried with results in comments

```
pid = $(this).next('.content_td').text(); // no value
pid = $(this).next('.projects_contentTable td a').text();// no value
pid = $(this).next('a').text(); // no value    
pid = $('.projects_contentTable .content_td:eq(3) a').text(); // no value
pid = $('.projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').text(); // all the values from the column... I just want the one from this row
```

As you can see I apparently just do not get how this works. My desire is to get the value of the Job# for the exact row that the icon I click is in. No more, no less. I need this value to send in an `AJAX` post and its driving me nuts. I know there's at least 5 ways to get this value, the more you can come up with the better, I just want to understand how this works. Your help is appreciated

Comment: As explained in [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/next/), `.next()` gets the immediately following _sibling_ element - and your img element that was clicked doesn't have a sibling.

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess I just didn't understand that correctly. So the next 'td' over in the same 'tr' is not the sibling?

Comment: Right. As in real life, siblings have the same parent. The td is a sibling of the other td because they are both children of the tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the parent (td) of your img before calling `next()`. `$(this).parent().next('td').text();`

Comment: thank you very much. This worked. So I have to get the parent(), which is the 'tr'?

Comment: No, the parent is the <td> because the class view_project_record is in it. So you need to target the parent first, the <td>, because there's is noting after <img> so you were targeting nothing.

Comment: ooohhhh, see now that makes sense. Thanks a ton my friend, answer will be accepted asap

Answer (score 0):

use `.children()` insted of `.next()`

Comment: The click event is on the images within the tds, so children won't work.